# Induced voltage of an inductor with a hollow core: can it produce current?

Tags: inductor, inductance, coil, ohms-law, induction

Hello I'm trying to understand a concept here: if I have a coil wound around a tube, with liquid flowing through the tube, will the electrical flux generated by the coil be enough to perform electrolysis?

My apologies for the original format.

Comment: If your reaction is activated by *magnetic* fields then yes. Inductors generate *magnetic* fields.

Comment: Thank you, do you mind explaining what you mean by activated?

Comment: The energy needed to initiate a reaction.

Answer (score 2):

(sorry, too long for a comment)

You are juggling terms around assuming they mean something in the context they happend to land in.

```
If I have a coil on an AC or DC circuit acting as an inductor.
```

A coil *is* an inductor, so what do you mean by *acting*?

And AC or DC will make a big difference lateron, so make up your mind.

```
Inducing a voltage of say x.
```

'Inducing a voltage' is a weird concept when the coil is driven by a source.

```
If I put a liquid substance inside the coil with a resistance of say y,
```

What do you mean by 'resistance'? The inverse of magnetic permeability?

```
will that produce a current of z in the substance if I divide the induced voltage by the resistance of the substance?.
```

Now you are realy off to fairyland. You seem to divide the  magnetic field strength by a resistance to get a current.

Note that a static magnetic field (remember: choose AC or DC) will never induce voltage or current in something that is static (= non-moving).

```
(I understand, to derive resistance you must calculate from resistivity).
```

That doesn't make any sense to me.

```
Thank you for taking the time to read the question.
```

Thanks. I'm off to get an asperin against the induced headache.

Comment: Ha. My apologies, but thank you for taking the time.